# QML Popup Overlay.modal transition not working

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have the following QML component which uses the `Overlay.modal` functionality to blur and dim the background:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Popup {
    readonly property color backdropColor

    id: root
    visible: true
    padding: 50
    modal: true
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 500
    height: 300

    contentItem: CB.Button {}

    background: CB.Card {}

    Overlay.modal: GaussianBlur {
        source: ShaderEffectSource {
            sourceItem: root.parent
            live: true
        }
        radius: 10
        samples: radius * 2

        Rectangle {
            id: backdropDim

            color: backdropColor
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }

    exit: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 1; to: 0; duration: 120 }
        NumberAnimation { target: backdropDim; property: "opacity"; from: 1; to: 0; duration: 120 }
    }
    enter: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1; duration: 120 }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have the background fade out (just like the popup itself, which works). To do that I gave the Rectangle of the background the id `backdropDim`.
However as soon as the modal get closed, the `Overlay.modal` disappears and I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: backdropDim is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? / How can I make the backdrop disappear with a smooth transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Overlay.modal` is a `Component`, which (in C++ terms) is like a class definition, not an instance of that class. You're trying to access a member of a class but you don't actually have a reference to the instance of that class.

The best way to fix this is to pull out the property (`opacity`) that you want to change so that it is outside that Component definition:

```
Popup {
    // Maintain backdrop opacity outside of the modal component
    property real backdropOpacity: 1.0
```

Then use that new property inside your Component:

```
        Rectangle {
            id: backdropDim

            color: backdropColor
            anchors.fill: parent
            opacity: backdropOpacity    // <--
        }
```

And finally also use that property in your Transition:

```
    exit: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 1; to: 0; duration: 120 }
        NumberAnimation { property: "backdropOpacity"; from: 1; to: 0; duration: 120 }
    }
```

***UPDATE:***

The `Popup` object hides/shows the modal component by changing its `opacity` property. So you can easily animate that by using a `Behavior` rather than a transition.

```
    Overlay.modal: GaussianBlur {
        source: ShaderEffectSource {
            sourceItem: root.parent
            live: true
        }
        radius: 10
        samples: radius * 2

        Rectangle {
            id: backdropDim

            color: backdropColor
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Behavior on opacity {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 120
            }
        }

    }

    exit: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 1; to: 0; duration: 120 }
    }
    enter: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1; duration: 120 }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work. The backdrop disappears instantly without a transition

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It seems that `Popup` must immediately hide the overlay component when closed, ignoring transitions for some reason. I'll see if I can find a workaround for that. Still I hope the info was helpful on accessing the property value outside the `Component`.

Comment: yes, that works, thank you! How did you find that? I didn't find it documented anywhere, to me this looked like a bug (or missing documentation). Or did you just try out random things?

Comment: Just an educated guess, really. I tried looking in the docs, but couldn't find it. I first thought it would be changing the `visible` property, but testing that showed its value never changed. So I figured it had to be `opacity`.